# refersh the tabs that are opend in all windows(multiple window)in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, tabs

I am using a code to update/refresh all the tabs in all the browser, specifically same application opened in multiple browser. I need to refresh/ update the tabs in all multiple window.

```
   var queryInfo = {
         currentWindow:true
           };
   chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function (tabs) {
     for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: tabs[i].url});
        }
    });
```

If I give current window true current window tabs are updated if I give false other window tab is updated. I want to update tabs in all multiple window.

How can I do it?

Comment: why don't you use a push solution (SSE, Websocket) ?

Comment: sorry didnt get u

Comment: why you have to refresh your browser ?

Comment: i have used a code to remove the cookie.after removing cookie i need to refersh/reload that page.
 var url = "http" + (all_cookies[i].secure ? "s" : "") + "://" + domainCookie + all_cookies[i].path;
                   chrome.cookies.remove({"url": url, "name": all_cookies[i].name});